# Apply patches created with git log -p

Tags: git, patch

I have a file of patches (all of which apply to a single file) generated with

```
git log -p file-of-interest.txt >patches.txt
```

Now I want to apply these patches in another repo, but when I try

```
git am patches.txt
```

I get the error message "Patch format detection failed."

(`git apply` does not work either). Which is the correct way to apply these patches?

Edit: What I want to do is to extract all changes to a single file between two commits into a set of patches, and then apply those changes in another repo. `git log -p from..to -- the-file` will generate the diff. If it is not possible to apply the patch from `git log`, is it possible to make `format-patch` (or another command) generate the patches for only a single file?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to break the patches down into individual patches. You could do that manually from your `git log -p` output, then use `git apply` to apply them in sequence. `git log -p` output wasn't really intended for `git` to process...

But a better option would be to use `git format-patch` to create the sequence of patch files for you (no manual splitting needed), then use `git am` to apply them all in one go...

```
git format-patch -o <output_directory> <from_revision>..<to_revision> -- file-of-interest.txt
```

Also note that `git am` expects email-formatted patches (like those produced by `git format-patch`, which is why you get "Patch format detection failed"). Patches generated with `diff` or `git diff` should be applied with `git apply`, not `git am`. But the `git format-patch` / `git am` workflow is more flexible and generally more robust.

Comment: Ah, format-patch supports limiting to a file. That was not in the docs

Comment: @erikkallen You're right, it's not documented very well. It's there, sorta, but in terms like "<common diff options>" and "see 'SPECIFYING REVISIONS' section in gitrevisions(7)"...

Comment: Not always the hash obtained from git log are consecutive. Would that work also ?

Comment: What if I am not the one who generated the patch? I have a patch file received from someone else. I can't re-create it.

Answer (score 1):

If you format the hash resulting from git log prepending the number of the path with the "-" symbol then all the patchs can be generated at once in different files. Example:

```
git format-patch $(git log --reverse 073dd505f..fff28ff65 --pretty="%H" -- the/needed/path | awk '{print -NR, " ", $0}')
```

That will cover all the filter that you can apply from git log. They are not allways consecutive commits. For example taking the patchs corresponding to a given user:

```
git format-patch $(git log --reverse --author="John Doe" --pretty="%H" -- the/needed/path | awk '{print -NR, " ", $0}')
```

The --reverse option is needed to give you the patch in chronological order, because git log give the most recents first.

Answer (score 0):

git log won't generate a patch file in that way. Use git log to find out the commit numbers you want to compare and use git diff instead:

```
git diff 073dd505f fff28ff65 > changes.patch
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git diff hash1...hash2 >a.patch` to create a patch file only of the commits that hash2 has that hash1 doesn't have (note the 3 dots `...`). This would be equivalent to `git log -p hash1..hash2` (note the 2 dots `..`) but the output would be in a format that you could actually patch files with.

The more common `git diff hash1 hash2 >a.patch` will create a patch file of all differences between hash1 and hash2 including commits that hash1 has but hash2 doesn't.